# How to solve login loop problem

Tags: 18.04, login

I use ubuntu 18.04.5 and I have a login loop problem.I searched in the internet (for example Xauthority file) and nothing seems to work.It's extremely boring,because when I type my password and press ENTER ,I have to wait for about 10 sec to 1 minute(max) in order to login to my desktop.I searched a lot.
What can I do?

specs:
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i5-7200U (-MT-MCP-)
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel HD Graphics 620
Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430 / R7 M520]
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "login loop"? What you describe sounds like you have to log in a second time. Or is it more often? Does the graphical login work at all? And how about the text console (Ctrl-Alt-F2, back with Ctrl-Alt-F7)? Does it work better there?

Comment: With "login loop", I mean that sometimes when I have my laptop in sleep mode and want to login ,I type my password and when I push ENTER , I wait for about 10sec to 1 min(max time),but this not happens when I restart pc and login.It happens only and sometimes when I have my laptop in sleep mode and want to login.

Comment: So this is not a loop at all. It's a delay. You enter your password ONCE, and it takes a few seconds; but you get logged in without having to enter the password again, correct?

Comment: If this is the case, it might be some part of your hardware that is responding very slowly; all the individual components have to be woken up, and some of them might take a while. Some few seconds is quite normal, but I've never seen it take more than, say, 10 seconds at most. Since you see the password prompt, it's IMHO unlikely (but not impossible) that this is a graphics driver problem.

Comment: I have been using Ubuntu 18.04 for 2 years and I have this problem(not always,just sometimes)  7-8 months. Is there anything I can do to solve it?

Comment: Check the journal if there are any errors around the time you woke up the machine. My gut feeling is that it's really some piece of hardware being slow to wake up, or a problem of the driver of that hardware. Finding out which one it is is the challenge.

Comment: I searched about that delay before and someone says that the problem is solved by disable the floppy from bios.....

Comment: It can help, but there area also a lot of computer voodoo stories around. This will be hard to track down.

Comment: ppfff...Anyway ,thanks a lot for your time!!! I appreciate it.

Comment: Once you managed to log in, create a new account with administration privileges. Then check if this login issue persists with the new account as well. That way, you can determine whether the issue is a user account configuration issue, or a wider system related issue.